# Hibernate errors : No Persistence provider for EntityManager named my-unit

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, persistence

i've tried to put my `persistence.xml` in various parts of my Java project and i call it with this command:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-unit");
```

but it returns me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named my-unit
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:81)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

my `persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="my-unit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <!-- use encache provider-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"-->
        <!--value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.javax.cache.provider" value="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"/>-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash;use second level cache&ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash;use 3rd level cache&ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>-->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I use IntelliJ as IDE for Java and the `persistence.xml` file is under `META-INF` folder in `resources` folder, i have tried to check the project structure and all looks like nice.
I use hibernate as maven repository.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the persistence provider name

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

That will solve the problem.

Comment: Didn't help. This exact provider name is already in the persistence.xml file.